# determining complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

**Problem**

Let $f$ be holomorphic in $D=\{|x+iy|< 1\}$, with

1. $|f|\le |y|^{-1/2}$
2. $\lim_{r\rightarrow 1} f(re^{i\theta}) = 0$, for any $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$

Prove $f = 0$.

---

It is an old qualify problem, I think it seems enough if I apply maximum principle according to second condition[not sure...:)], I am not very sure how to use the first condition.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean $D = \{|x+iy|<1\}$ ?

Comment: @YoniRozenshein Actually I am not very sure, the problem just said $D$, I wonder the difference of these two cases.

Comment: @YoniRozenshein I know the difference now, the region should be a open disk. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @YoniRozenshein for pointing out an initial error, and to @Yimin for pointing out a solution.

Apply the DCT to Cauchy's integral formula.

Suppose $|z_0| < s <r <1$. Then $f(z_0) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_{\gamma_r} \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0} dz = \frac{1}{2 \pi } \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{f(r e^{i \theta})}{r e^{i \theta}-z_0} r e^{i \theta} d\theta$, from which we get $|f(z_0)| \le \frac{r}{2 \pi } \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{|f(r e^{i \theta})|}{|r e^{i \theta}-z_0|}   d\theta \le \frac{1}{2 \pi } \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{|f(r e^{i \theta})|}{|r e^{i \theta}-z_0|}   d\theta$.

Let $g_r (\theta) = \frac{|f(r e^{i \theta})|}{|r e^{i \theta}-z_0|}$, for $r \in (s,1)$. Since $|r e^{i \theta}-z_0|\ge s -|z_0|$, we have $g_r (\theta) \le \frac{|f(r e^{i \theta})|}{s -|z_0|}$, and hence $\lim_{r \uparrow 1} g_r (\theta) = 0$ for all $\theta$. To apply the DCT, we need to bound $g_r$ by some integrable function $g_1$.

We have $|f(r e^{i \theta})| \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{r |\sin \theta|}}$ by assumption, and $|\sin(x)| \ge \frac{1}{2} \min_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} |x-k\pi|$, which gives
$g_r (\theta) \le g_1(\theta)=  (\frac{1}{s-|z_0|} \frac{1}{\sqrt{s}}) \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\min_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} |\theta-k\pi|}} $. A small amount of work shows that $\int_0^{2 \pi} g_1 = 8\sqrt{\pi} (\frac{1}{s-|z_0|} \frac{1}{\sqrt{s}})  $, hence integrable.

It follows that $|f(z_0)| \le \frac{1}{2 \pi} \lim_{r \uparrow 1} \int_0^{2 \pi} g_r = 0$. Since $z_0 \in D$ was arbitrary, we are finished.

Comment: $|f(z)| \le 1$ for $z \in D$?

Comment: It seemed that if you use $|f(z)|\le |y|^{-1/2}$ to replace $|f(z)|\le1$, on the circle, this is integrable as well, then you can use DCT.

Comment: @YoniRozenshein: I did miss something, I missed the $-$ in the upper bound.

Comment: @YoniRozenshein: It is fixed now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Yimin: Thanks for pointing out that the bound is integrable.